# Can I have a Python script listen on a message queue continuously or do I have to loop?

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

My goal is to write a Python script that does some action when a message is received on Azure Service Bus (to a topic which it subscribes to). I know how to have it check to see if there is a message but where I am unclear is if it's recommended (or even possible) to listen continuously on the bus or if I have to just loop and check every x seconds for a new message.

Comment: make your program threaded and just have a while loop running on the thread so it doesnt block your main program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally for messageQueues like RabbitMQ one can write a python script which works using the callback methods, you just subscribe to the callback method of queue, and whenever a message arrives in queue, the callback is called for you.

Callback function

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)
```

subscribing to Queue

```
channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)
```

Source - http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

But, in case of Azure Service bus its not the same kind of resource, you can take a service bus as equivalent of Kafka, but since its a cloud resource azure or even any other cloud provider for that matter can't afford long running connections, the interfaces are rather poll and pull; as a good practice I suggest you use a technique called "back off polling" here is a sample pseudo code

```
currentBackoff = 0
maxBackOff = 10
while True:
    msg = Queue.getmessage()
    if msg != null:
        currentBackOff = 0
        print msg
        queue.DeleteMessage(msg)
    else:
        if currentBackOff < MaxBackOff:
            currentBackOff++
        sleep(currentBackOff)
```

Source - http://www.developerfusion.com/article/120619/advanced-scenarios-with-windows-azure-queues/

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation!